# Ubuntu install of Electric PR2 Desktop

Tags: ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric). I followed the tutorial on:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/PR2/electric

but when I try to do:
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-desktop
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-wg-pr2-desktop

I can't find those packages. Do you have any suggestion?

So, in the meanwhile, I installed:
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-wg-pr2-apps
which it works for me. Is it the same thing?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11881/ubuntu-install-of-electric-pr2-desktop/) by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all pr2 related debs have been released into Oneiric yet.  If you see any that you need please file a ticket with the maintainer of the stack.

[wg_pr2_apps](http://www.ros.org/wiki/wg_pr2_apps) is not the same as the meta package pr2-desktop.  pr2_desktop is a variant defined by http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html and http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0113.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0